# Rails 4 has_many through edit association on the show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I am building a Rails 4 app where I have 2 models and 1 for the association:

game.rb

```
    class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :participations
    has_many :players, :through => :participations

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :participations, :allow_destroy => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :players
end
```

player.rb

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

    has_many :participations
    has_many :games, :through => :participations

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :participations, :allow_destroy => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :games
end
```

participation.rb

```
class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :player
    belongs_to :game

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :game
end
```

The idea is that on almost daily the games are played, players get scores for each game ( this is kept in the participation model).

Everything works fine if I go to the games page select a game a see all the players that participated in that game and their scores.

What I can't seem to do is to be able to add players and their scores on the Game show page.
After the list with the players and want a form with a selector (players name to choose) and a text box to enter the score.

It would be better if this could be done with Ajax.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

I have this in my show view to display the player and their score:

```
<% @game.participations.each do |participation| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= participation.player.name %></td>
        <td><%= participation.score %></td>
        <td><%= participation.time %></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
```

**Update 2**

So I got it kind of working my Game#show page looks like this:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Date:</strong>
  <%= @game.date %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Time:</strong>
  <%= @game.time %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_game_path(@game) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', games_path %>

<hr>
<h4>Players</h4>
<hr>


<table class="table table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Player</th>
      <th>Score</th>
      <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <% @game.participations.each do |participation| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= participation.player.name %></td>
        <td><%= participation.score %></td>
        <td><%= participation.time %></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<%= form_for :participation, :url => participations_path, :html => {:method => :post} do |f| %>
<table>
<tr>
  <td><%= f.collection_select :player_id, Player.all, :id, :name %></td>
  <td><%= f.text_field :score %></td>
  <td><%= f.text_field :time %></td>
</tr>
</table>
<%= f.submit  %>
<% end %>
```

Now everything works but how do I pass the game_id to the form, since I am in the Game#show view I have @game.id I tried something like this but doesn't work:

```
<%= form_for :participation, :url => participations_path, :html => {:method => :post}, :game_id => @game.id do |f| %>
```

Comment: Check out the [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) gem.

Comment: @nathanvda I will take a look and let you know.

Comment: I tried cocoon but I get this error
undefined method `reflect_on_association' for NilClass:Class

Answer (score 0):

You have your associations mixed up. When you set up a has_many, :through => association the associated model is required to link the models - in your case 'participations'.

It only acts as a link and you can't directly view all games with @game.participations. You need to reference the other model, so in your case @game.players. For example:

```
<% @game.players.each do |player| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= player.name %></td>
        <td><%= player.score %></td>
        <td><%= player.time %></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Furthermore the nested attributes method is **not** required for 'participations', it is only a link model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :participations, :allow_destroy => true
```

**UPDATE:**

If you would like to know how to add fields for a has_many association with AJAX I'd recommend checking out these two Railscasts. I've used this method on a recent project and it works beautifully:

[Nested forms: Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

[Nested forms: Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me. All my associations work fine. Since I am testing them right now and it's ok.
Also my player model doesn't have a score or a time field, this fields are in the participation model(since for each game it's a unique score and time played)
I wanted to be able to add players to a specific game from the show game view

Comment: Aha I see. Your Participation model in your original post doesn't indicate this, hence my misunderstanding. Please see an update of my original post.